# DS-5 debugger target support

Tags: arm, ds-5

ARM DS-5 claims to support different kinds of targets. What are different types of targets supported by DS-5? How can I connect to these targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find if a target (device, dev board, virtual platform, android emulator) is supported, then you need to check two things

Step 1 : Check if a device is explicitly supported by looking at https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/supported-devices

Step 2 : Check how to connect the DS-5 to the device to achieve the desired type of debugging. DS-5 Debugger supports following debug connections

- CADI connection - FVP targets - JTAG style debug.
- GDB connection - Any target that can run GDB server.
- DSTREAM debug adapter connection - Development boards - JTAG style debug.
- UlinkPro debug adapter connection - Development boards - JTAG style debug.
- ADB connection - Any target supporting adb connection - Android devices, dev boards etc.
- VSTREAM IP connection - RTL simulator targets - JTAG style debug.
- CMSIS-DAP over USB connection - Development boards that support CMSIS-DAP over USB connection - JTAG style debug.